# Check if the string is only numbers and or has one decimal after at least one digit and after the period allow up to 3 numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to create a reg ex pattern to match a string that has at least one number and at the most two numbers before the optional decimal point and if a decimal point is included their should be at least one to three digits at most after it.

For example the following values should validate.

```
0
0.0
0.00
0.000
00
00.0
00.00
00.000
```

The following valuse should not validate.

```
0.
00.
0.0000
00.0000
```

Here is my code so far

```
function check($string){
    if(preg_match('/^[0-9][0-9]?(?:\.[0-9]{1,3})$/', $string)){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this one `^[0-9]{1,2}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3})?$`

Comment: @rgen3 Thanks it worked again thanks for all the help .

Comment: @rgen3: Put it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex

`^[0-9]{1,2}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3})?$`

synonym with group sign `\d`

`^\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,3})?$`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simpler regex.

```
<?php 

$tests = [  '0',
            '0.0',
            '0.00',
            '0.000',
            '00',
            '00.0',
            '00.00',
            '00.000',
            '0.',
            '00.',
            '0.0000',
            '00.0000'
        ];


$regex_pattern = '/^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,3})?$/';

foreach($tests as $each_test){
    echo $each_test," -----------> ",var_dump(1 === preg_match($regex_pattern,$each_test)),"<br/>";
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
0 -----------> bool(true) 
0.0 -----------> bool(true) 
0.00 -----------> bool(true) 
0.000 -----------> bool(true) 
00 -----------> bool(true) 
00.0 -----------> bool(true) 
00.00 -----------> bool(true) 
00.000 -----------> bool(true) 
0. -----------> bool(false) 
00. -----------> bool(false) 
0.0000 -----------> bool(false) 
00.0000 -----------> bool(false)
```

Answer (score 2):

`'/^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$/'` is the exact pattern you are searching for.

But many atimes its good to write a function that keeps things nice neat and simple in case you want to expand on the idea

```
function OptionalDecimal($numstr) {
//use string count to check for the times decimal points appears in the string
if (substr_count($numstr,".") == 0) {
    if(preg_match('/^\d{1,2}$/', $numstr)) return 'true';
}
if (substr_count($numstr,".") == 1) {
    if(preg_match('/^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}$/', $numstr)) return 'true';
}
return 'false';
}

echo OptionalDecimal("4.7");
```

This function does the same thing